# How do I use enum values when their type is defined indirectly in another unit?

Tags: delphi, enums, scope

I am trying to reduce the number of `Uses` and am running into problems with `Enums`

```
(* original unit, where types are defined etc *)
unit unit1;
type
  TSomeEnumType = (setValue1, setValue2, ...);
...
```

```
(* global unit where all types are linked *)
unit unit2;
uses unit1;
type
  TSomeEnumType = unit1.TSomeEnumType;
...
```

```
(* form unit that will use the global unit *)
unit unitform;
uses unit2;
...
procedure FormCreate(Sender : TObject);
var ATypeTest : TSomeEnumType;
begin
  ATypeTest := setValue1; (* error says undeclared *)
  ATypeTest := TSomeEnumType(0); (* Works but there's not point in use enum *)
end;
...
```

The problem is that in the unitform `setValue1` says it is undeclared.  How can I get around this?

Comment: @kabstergo. Are you trying to remove unused units from the uses clause or just reduce the number of units in the uses clause. In the later case, just refactor the code in one or fewer units. In the former there are tools out there that can help you do that.

Comment: ops sorry, i always mix up this with php

Comment: FWIW: I'm not sure if I would call this "optimizing". ;-)

Comment: @J. Gonzalez im only trying to reduce the end utilization (forms, etc). the ideia is to put all defined classes, types, enum in one single unit

Comment: @Uli Gerhardt i know it would be better keep each unit separate, but we already faced some prob thanks to the large number of units in the Project when we have to change a class or move to another unit for better organization. thats why we decide to "resume" this units in 1, 2 or 3 max for better manage purpose.

Comment: Perhaps *scoped enums* can help here. Instead of writing `setValue1`, write `TSomeEnumType.setValue1`. I expect you'll get the *unit2* type, and from there the compiler will find the type's value. I think this was introduced in one of the XE versions.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy. As per OP comment, it's not just about enums: "he idea is to put all defined classes, types, enum in one single unit". Therefore the title should be changed accordingly.

Comment: @J.Gonzalez, *this* question *is* just about enums. Kabsergo has already figured out how to use fewer units by re-declaring things in other units, but is stuck because the enum values are not automatically carried over with the enum types.

Comment: Don't do this. Unless you enjoy self-inflicted pain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not only import the type, but also the constants, like so:

```
unit unit1;
type
  TSomeEnumType = (setValue1, setValue2, ...);
...
```

```
/* global unit where all types are linked */
unit unit2;
uses unit1;
type
  TSomeEnumType = unit1.TSomeEnumType;
const
  setValue1 = unit1.setValue1;
  setValue2 = unit1.setValue2;
  ...
```

Note that if the idea is that in the end, all units should use `unit2` and never `unit1`, but you want to allow units that currently use `unit1` to continue compiling, another way of dealing with that is to remove `unit1`, put `TSomeEnumType` in `unit2` directly, and in your project options, put `unit1=unit2` in the unit aliases. Every time a unit then does `uses unit1;`, it will really pull in `unit2`.

Comment: But there's no point in doing so, as you're still using (and linking) the relevant parts of `unit1`. There's no need to do this, nor is there any "optimization" from doing it. (Not downvoting, just mentioning.)

Comment: @KenWhite As I understand the question, the idea is that *other* units only have `unit2` in the `uses` list, and the enumeration type is usable in those other units. I'm not claiming this has any effect on the generated code. The question does ask to "optimize", but I don't think it's the kind of optimisation you mean.

Comment: My point was that the poster referred to it as "optimizing", and it does no such thing, and it's actually more cumbersome than just using `unit1` directly as it should be used. As I said, I didn't downvote, but wanted to make it clear that the poster's intent to do this accomplishes nothing except to add a level of clutter to the code and make maintenance harder. "Let's add a new value to `TSomeEnumType`. Let's see, that's in this global unit... Oops, it's not there at all, even though the code says it is! It's in `unit1` instead. Wasted that time."

Comment: (continued) There are times that defining everything at a higher (wider) scope and then narrowing it like this is useful, but going from the lower to a higher one seldom (if ever) is, IMO.

Comment: @KenWhite I think I see your point. I can see the point of the question to put more types together in units in order to avoid long uses lists, but there are other options for dealing with that. Will edit.

Comment: @KenWhite yes i agree with that, i think we have two points of view here, this is not about optimize the execution at all since there's redundant type along the units, but we believe that it will reduce maintenance time since we only have to fix 1 or 2 main units instead of go on every unit of every Project to add ou remove some unit

Comment: @kabstergo: You think wrong. :-) And you're slowing compile times, and increasing line count, and limiting the ability to reuse the code. And grep or something similar makes it very easy to find the units where you have to remove something, and the compiler will tell you when you need to add something. But it's not my time you're wasting. :-) And when you find out this is a very bad idea, and that there's a reason for separating things out properly, you're the one who has to undo it all again.