# why delphi use type alias if this was proven to not be a good approach?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

a year a go i was trying to do something as this question shows [How do I use enum values when their type is defined indirectly in another unit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925937/how-do-i-use-enum-values-when-their-type-is-defined-indirectly-in-another-unit) and i was encourage from other users to leave this mentality couse it was not a good approach for various reason.

well, a few days back i was doing some custom dialog for our software and i thought to use some of the types provided nativelly by delphi instead of declared my owns. my surprise was that the file `vcl.dialogs` has the same technique i was encourage not to do as the code shows:

```
{ Message dialog }
mtWarning   = System.UITypes.TMsgDlgType.mtWarning;
mtError = System.UITypes.TMsgDlgType.mtError;
mtInformation   = System.UITypes.TMsgDlgType.mtInformation;
mtConfirmation  = System.UITypes.TMsgDlgType.mtConfirmation;
mtCustom    = System.UITypes.TMsgDlgType.mtCustom;

mbYes   = System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbYes;
mbNo    = System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbNo;
mbOK    = System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbOK;
mbCancel    = System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbCancel;
mbAbort = System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbAbort;
mbRetry = System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbRetry;
mbIgnore    = System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbIgnore;
mbAll   = System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbAll;
mbNoToAll   = System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbNoToAll;
mbYesToAll  = System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbYesToAll;
mbHelp  = System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbHelp;
mbClose = System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbClose;
```

so basically delphi does a buch of replication of this types that are originally declared on `System.UITypes` to the `vcl.dialogs` file.

so the question is: there's a logical explanation to why he does this? is delphi bad writed? this approach is not that bad? if neither there's a adequate way to use this?

Comment: They are dealing with back compat issues. They wouldn't design it like this from scratch.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thx to the firemonkey thing or this is older?

Comment: It's for x-plat ShowMessage, I guess. Don't recall it for CLX so I guess it's FMX. Whatever, don't do this at home!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not type aliases. These are actually constants. What's more these are true constants rather than typed constants. This means that you can import either `Vcl.Dialogs` or `System.UITypes` and use `mtWarning`.

Embarcadero have done this to allow cross-platform use of this type, and yet maintain backwards compatibility with existing code. The cross-platform need arose when FireMonkey was introduced.

There was a need to use this type in platforms other than Windows. However, the VCL is Windows only. So having the type declared in a VCL namespace unit does not work. Hence the introduction of `System.UITypes`. In order to allow existing code to continue compiling, the designers elected to export the same values from `Vcl.Dialogs`.

New code should use `System.UITypes` to gain access to this enumerated type.

Comment: They're constants defined along with a type alias, where the type alias is omitted from the question. The constants are defined too because the type alias alone would merely declare an unusable enumeration type.

Comment: @hvd OK. It would be quite usable though. You don't need to be able to see the enumerated type to be able to write an enumeration literal. I can just write `foo(mtWarning)` without having to reference the enumerated type. But I fully see what you are getting at. And indeed any code that did reference the type would be hosed. So the type alias is needed too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There was a better way of doing what you wanted to accomplish. Having the same enumeration type available in separate units causes problems with maintenance, and you didn't really need that for what you wanted to accomplish.

There is not a better way of doing what the VCL developers want to accomplish, as far as I can see. The VCL developers *do* really need the same enumeration type to be available in two separate units, and are prepared to deal with any maintenance difficulties caused by it. If this were any other library, they could say "just add `System.UITypes` to your `uses` list", and remove the type from `Vcl.Dialogs`. However, the VCL takes great efforts to maintain compatibility, to make sure that code that compiled with older versions of Delphi still compiles with later versions. It needs to, because any previously valid code that fails to compile is a potential lost customer, for Delphi itself far more so than for various third-party libraries.

Comment: There is only one type. The declarations in `Vcl.Dialogs` are constants.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know, but I see how my answer implies otherwise. Will edit.

Answer (score 1):

Explanation is simple - there are too many old code that does not know anything about ''System.UITypes'' and ''vcl.dialogs''. They just know about ''dialogs'' module.

And this old programms will still compile and run. So it just backward compatibility and preparings for cross-platform development I think.